# Rails ActiveRecord Transaction vs Class Transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions

I have a doubt about Rails Transaction type. What the diffence between them and whem to use each one ?

**Active Record Transactions**

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    david.withdrawal(100)
    mary.deposit(100)
end
```

**Class Transactions**

```
Account.transaction do
    balance.save!
    account.save!
end
```

**Instance Transactions**

```
account.transaction do
    balance.save!
    account.save!
end
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 11):

#### AR Transaction is the Class Transaction

```
Account < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Account.transaction(block) == ActiveRecord::Base.transaction(block)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/transaction

#### Instance Transaction is a convenience method

The instance method of DB transactions is a convenience method for more syntactically beautiful code.

You could do this instead.

```
account = Account.find(1)
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  account.save!
end
```

And it would be the same for any of the above. Either way, it's generating SQL code in a transaction.

The proof is in the source code of the instance method for transactions.

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb, line 276
def transaction(options = {}, &block)
  self.class.transaction(options, &block)
end
```

https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Transactions/transaction